# Why is the default top-level subvolume (id=5) not shown in btrfs subvolume list -a?

Tags: mount, btrfs

On the [btrfs wiki page about subvolumes](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume) it says that by default, at creation of a btrfs (i.e `make.btrfs <devicenode>`) a *top level* subvolume with an subvolume ID=5 is created.

> A freshly created filesystem is also a subvolume, called top-level, internally has an id 5. This subvolume cannot be removed or replaced by another subvolume.

I tried hence showing this subvolume using the `btrfs subvolume list -a /btrfs.mountpoint`, but it does not show up, why?

**update**
In an attempt of (self-help) I tried to find out more about this top-level subvolume ID=5, which is (as stated) above created. I hence tried to mount to real btrfs root (which I supposed to be subvolume id=0) and look at its content like this:

```
# mount a specific subvolume of a btrfs 
$> mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=0 /dev/sda /mnt
# show the output of the "."-entry of the subvolume-root (show inodevalue)
$> ls /mnt -lai | head -n 2
total 112656
 256 drwxr-xr-x  1 root root      432 May 25 09:08 .
```

after unmounting again I did the same (using this time the subvolume ID=5)

```
# mount a specific subvolume of a btrfs 
$> mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=5 /dev/sda /mnt
# show the output of the "."-entry of the subvolume-root (show inodevalue)
$> ls /mnt -lai | head -n 2
total 112656
 256 drwxr-xr-x  1 root root      432 May 25 09:08 .
```

and it produces the very same output (just like the subvolume ID=5) was the root subvolume and ID=5 at the same time. Maybe this shows some light why it does not show up with `btrfs subvolume list -a` command?

Anyway since even the root volume is assigned a subvolid (at least for use with mount) it seems odd that nothing shows up at `btrfs subvolume list -a`.

(update corrected, the mistake of pasting the wrong btrfs subvolume command)

*update2*

the man pages for the `btrfs` and the `btrfs-progs` and the cited wiki page (see beginning of question), are not very precise in laying out how
in terms of filesystem volumne-root, subvolume, subvolids.... btrfs is created.

According do some explaining on the mailing list it is that:

> [a]ll subvolumes are accessible from the volume mounted when you use `-o
>   subvolid=0.` (Note that **0 is not the real ID of the root volume**, it's
>   just *a shortcut for mounting it*.) [emphasis added]
>   (source https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg17141.html)

this leads me to believe that, despite the first citation the subvolume id 5 is the root (at least in my case).

Anyway some years ago the btrfs mailing list showed [a case](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg07511.html) where not even all ordinary snapshots have been correctly reported by btrfs subvolume list , making me believe that there is also the possibility that all the problem of not showing the subvolume could be a bug.

More so then ever I would appreciate somebody shading some light on this, in an answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah, it is strange.  I had the same problem. The first subvolume I create has the id 5.  The main file system has no subvolume number.

Comment: Invisible root volume was always the most confusing thing for me in regards to btrfs.